# How to make editText.setText work with setFilters

Tags: android, kotlin

I use this code to allow the user to rename a file in internal storage

```
    val alertDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Name your file")

    val editText = EditText(context)
    
    editText.setFilters(arrayOf(
        InputFilter { src, _, _, _, _, _ ->
                if (src == "") {
                    Log.d("filters", "case1")
                    return@InputFilter src
                    }
                else if (src.toString().matches(Regex("[a-zA-Z0-9 éèùàêâî/_-]+"))) {
                    Log.d("filters", "case2")
                                        src
                                    }
                else {
                    Log.d("filters", "case3")
                    ""
                    }
                }
                ))
   
    editText.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT
    editText.setText(fichier) // fichier = the former name of the file (String)
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(editText)
    alertDialogBuilder.show()
```

But the setText does not work with setFilters, so the editText remains empty and does not show the old name of the file.

This is my log :

`D/filters: case3`

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried your code and it is working fine. Are you sure that the variable `fichier` is not empty?

Comment: I have just realized I didn't remove the extension from the name of the file. The problem came from the dot. Thank you for your help.